# Trying to solve with python map function with lambda expression inside for loop

Tags: python

```
n=10
fun=list(map(lambda x:[j for j in range(x)],n))
print(fun)
```

expected output is:

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: `map` expects an iterable you are passing an integer. also why are you using list comprehension _and_ map?

Comment: why dont you just use `list(map(str, range(n)))` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
# using map (map works on an iterable)
n=10
fun=lambda x: (range(x)) # remember this is a function (so call it)
fun=list(map(str, fun(n)))
print(fun)

# directly
n=10
fun=list(map(str, (range(n))))
print(fun)
```

```
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Python docs for reference:

- `map()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map
- `range()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range
- `lambda()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html?highlight=lambda#ast.Lambda

Comment: you dont need `list(range(n))`. `range(n)` is already an iterable.